# Como remover valores duplicados de consulta em duas tabelas?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Estou fazendo uma consulta em duas tabelas (alunos e usuários) e pegando os valores de id, nome e email. Logo após faço uma union entre elas. Porém, queria que não tivesse linhas com valores duplicados para o campo email. Preciso destes valores porque a partir da escolha do usuário a tabela colaboradores_projeto terá as chaves estrangeiras fk_aluno ou fk_usuario preenchida. O campo email é para diferenciar as linhas, pq apesar de serem tabelas diferentes o id pode ser o mesmo. Essa consulta é para alimentar um Select Multiple, onde o usuário vai dizer quem são os colaboradores que vão participar do projeto.

**Consulta**

```
$alunos = DB::table('alunos')->where('status','Ativo')->select('email', 'nome', 'id');
$usuarios = DB::table('users')->where('status','Ativo')->select('email', 'nome', 'id');
$colaboradores = $alunos->union($usuarios);
```

**View**

```
{!! Form::select('colaboradores[]', $colaboradores->pluck('nome'), null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'multiple'=>'true')) !!}
```

**Tabelas**

Usuários

```
ID   |   nome   |   email  |   funcao   | ... |
```

Alunos

```
ID   |   nome   |   email  |   matricula   | ... |
```

colaboradores_projeto

```
ID |   fk_projeto   |   fk_aluno   |   fk_usuario   |
```

Estou precisando de ajuda nessa parte, porque já estou com este problema a alguns dias.

Comment: Consegue postar a estrutura das tabelas ou apenas a consulta sql?

Comment: Inseri as informações Maurivan.

Comment: Para selecionar valores de duas tabelas você pode usar `join` ou a intenção e unir usando `union`.

Comment: Uma sugestão seria dar group by email. Testa e posta o resultado.

Comment: Não tem relação entre as tabelas para fazer o join.

Comment: Creio que em vez de usar um "join" para resolver esse seu problema, provavelmente uma reestruturação das tabelas seria melhor.

Comment: Uma solução mais simples é criar 2 tabelas de relacionamento ao invés de 1, já que são coisas diferentes pelo que você disse: uma usuarios_projeto e outra alunos_projeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em SQL, uma solução simples mas não muito eficiente quanto ao processamento:

```
select email, nome, id from usuarios
union
select email, nome, id from alunos where email not in (select email from usuarios);
```

Comment: Funcionou como queria, obrigado. Da forma que está estruturado não vejo como fazer consulta lá muito eficiente.

Comment: Uma última coisa: estou tendo problema com a view. {!! Form::select('colaboradores[]', $colaboradores->nome, null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'multiple'=>'true')) !!}.  Dar esse erro: Trying to get property of non-object. Tem outra forma a não ser substituir o select manualmente e fazer foreach?

Comment: sugiro você marcar essa pergunta como respondida e fazer uma nova pergunta melhor estruturada.

Comment: Essa `union` vai funcionar, mas você continua sem saber quem é usuário e quem é aluno, pois virou tudo `id` e continua podendo retornar ids repetidos.

Para saber a origem, poderia fazer: `select email, nome, id as fk_usuario from usuarios
union
select email, nome, id as fk_aluno from alunos where email not in (select email from usuarios);`

Answer (score 0):

Leia sobre JOIN futuramente vai facilitar sua vida e te dar consultas mais rapidas e eficientes http://www.bosontreinamentos.com.br/mysql/mysql-inner-join-consultar-dados-em-duas-ou-mais-tabelas-29/ um links bom pra começar.